# Ruby on rails - slow 200 records query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I work on a travel app, with a page that load 250 countries, with one image per country. In production, this page is really slow, and I want to know if someone have a solution to handle loading records 20 per 20 for example, or to have a more faster loading ?

Currently, here is my basic query :

```
@worlds = World.all.sort_by(&:count_visited).reverse
```

Thank you !

**EDIT**

I can't use a paginate gem because I'm using list.js, to easily find a country. So I need that all my records being on the same page.

Comment: Is it the process of loading each image that is "slow" or the whole page?

Comment: Also, can you show the implementation of the `count_visited` method?

Comment: @MrYoshiji When I remove image, everything load really fast, so I think that the problem come from images, and `count_visited` is field not a method

Comment: If it is a field, then use the DB to order by that column: `World.all.order(count_visited: :desc)`, it's gonna be way faster than ruby. I suggest you lazy-load the images. Try googling "load images async" and you will find tons of solutions

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways to solve your problem:
**Solution #1:**
Compress the resolution of the images using one of below:
A) Using any **image Editor**
B) Using **paperclip-compression** gem library
**https://github.com/emrekutlu/paperclip-compression**

**Solution #2:**
If you want to keep the current resolution, then you can use **will_paginate** gem library to show 10,20 or any number of records per page:
https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

**Controller:**

```
## perform a paginated query:
@posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page])

# or, use an explicit "per page" limit:
Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
```

**ERB file:**

```
## render page links in the view:
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just edited my question, I can't use a paginate gem, because I'm using list.js to filter country on their name, so I need all countries on the same page

Comment: @AntoninMrchd what is the average size of images ?

Comment: 200x300 and on my S3 bucket : 4,8MB

Comment: @AntoninMrchd 4,8MB per image?

Comment: Yes, I think they are too big, but if I use "medium" size proposed by AWS, the quality is very damaging

Comment: @AntoninMrchd I think you need to compress, I know JPEG should be highly compressed, try PNG format. By the way, I have updated my answer and I have added a gem library you can use to do the compression on the fly.

Comment: What about lazy loading of the images?

Comment: @Shiko Are you sure that paperclip-compression compress image on the fly ?

Comment: @AntoninMrchd I can understand that from their library, they have your original images and they compress them based on your configuration which you may change at any time.